# How to change shells via script?

Tags: bash, sudo, csh

I have to repeat following operation a lot of times, hence I want to automate it.

```
sudo su
tcsh
cd $workDir
```

Here `$workDir` is set in `~/.tcshrc`. I tried writing two shells scripts. Script1 is `temp.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo su
./temp.csh
```

Script2 is `temp.csh`

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh
tcsh
cd $workDir
```

But it doesn't work as expected i.e. I don't see the cshell prompt (still on bash prompt, unlike in without-script approach) neither have I CDed into $workDir. Any help/pointers?

Comment: “It doesn't work as expected.” So what did you expect? What did you observe? How do the two differ?

Comment: @Gilles thanks for feedback. updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `workDir="/dev/"; sudo su -c tcsh -c "cd $workDir; echo \$PWD"` to change the folder during script.

Just remember to escape all `$`.

**EDIT**

Why wouldn't you do so:

`sudo ./tcsh.csh`

And inside tcsh.csh contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh
cd $workDir  # need to set $workDir somewhere, depends on you
blabla
```

Comment: Thanks. Where does `sudo su` go? I'd like to automate typing it as well.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I tried the part under 'Edit', but it's not working as expected. I have to be able to change the terminal prompt after running `sudo ./tcsh.csh`, which doesn't seem to happen. Also I have `$workDir` declared in `~/.tcshrc`. Should I rather declare it in `~/.bashrc`?

Answer (score 0):

You can doing something like this from [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) (using *here-doc*) :

```
tcsh<<EOF
command1
command2
(...)
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run

```
sudo su
./temp.csh
```

this executes an interactive shell as root (`sudo su`), then when that shell terminates the csh script is executed. Similarly, the `temp.csh` script first executes an interactive tcsh, then changes its current directory just before exiting.

To execute a csh script as root, run

```
sudo ./temp.csh
```

To execute an interactive instance of tcsh as root, which I think is what you're trying to do, run

```
sudo tcsh
```

To execute that tcsh instance in a particular directory, change the directory before running sudo.

```
cd /path/to/directory && sudo tcsh
```

Note that in many installations, `sudo` wipes most of the environment, so don't expect environment variables set in the wrapper script to be available in the tcsh session.

You can't pass a script to execute at the beginning of a tcsh session, other than the profile files (`/etc/csh.login` and `~/.login` for login shells, `/etc/csh.cshrc` and `~/.cshrc` for all tcsh instances). If you want to run some initial commands, put them in `~/.cshrc` (possibly inside a conditional construct). Alternatively, for commands that only execute programs, set environment variables, change the current directory and the like, you can use a wrapper script like the one below; this does not work to change the shell environment (for example, to set csh variables with `set`).

```
#!/bin/tcsh
# commands go here
cd $workdir
setenv foo bar
exec tcsh
```